# Retrieving word before a semicolon

Tags: java, string

I have string,

```
 String str ="public class Person {private String firstName;private String lastName;private int nId;}"
```

If i want to retrieve word which is before every semi colon , how would i do ?
so the output would be,

```
firstName
lastName
nId
```

Comment: have you tried something??

Comment: Try using [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). A string could be /(\w+);/g

Comment: You must have tried something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expression to target the word behind every semicolon:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str ="public class Person {private String firstName;private String lastName;private int nId;}";
    String pattern = "(\\w*);";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(str);

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

The word behind the semicolon is stored in `m.group(1)`.

#### Output:

```
firstName
lastName
nId
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string by `;`

```
String[] parts = string.split(";");
```

Then for each parts you can get last word

```
String lastWord = parts.substring(parts.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
```